# WordPress cannot automatically upgrade after latest version is installed

Tags: php, wordpress

all. I am trying to update WordPress to the latest version(4.9.1). The installation of new version of WordPress seems to be updated successfully as show in the picture. Except, my site was redirected to previous version's (4.9) about page after installation, and from the dashboard my site still shows the information of 'update available'. I double checked the version.php under wp-include. It shows the latest version number(4.9.1). I am wondering why my site doesn't detect the upgrade of wordpress? Appreciate if any one can advise the problem. Thank you.

Step 1: click the 'update now' to update WP.
[image]

Step 2: Update information page. It shows successful installation.
[image]

Step 3: Automatically redirect to version about page.
[image]

Step 4: Dashboard still showing old version number and prompt new version available.
[image]

Step 5: check version.php.
[image]

Comment: Try navigating to /wp-admin/upgrade.php and see if it gives you the option to force the update on your database.

Comment: Hi @ClaytonLeis, thanks for your reply.  wp-admin/upgrade.php page shows that no update required,  WordPress database is already up-to-date!

Comment: @ClaytonLeis Tried it already. Doesnt suggest upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whom it may concern. It was the cache issue on my server. After flushing the cache, it works.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you specify cache? I have the same problem and even updating manually disabling all plugins it does this.

Comment: Hi @Edža, it depends what cache your server implements. My case is FastCGI & Opcache. Hope it helps.

Comment: For me opcache file cache are disabled but I cleared it anyway. Doesnt seem to help. No other cache are enabled. Strange thing is I have 3 sites on that server. One are updating fine and two others not. :)

Comment: You may try to reboot your server to see if it works?

Comment: Doubt it. I dont see how it is related.